# Is it possible to set your locale for specific games / programs when running via Proton in Steam?

Tags: wine, games, steam, locale, japanese

I've got a few visual novels and light Japanese RPGs I'm attempting to play, and while entirely functional, the Japanese characters are displaying as boxes, which depending on the situation is actually quite debilitating.

As far as I can tell, it should run fine on a Japanese locale, though I haven't tested changing the full system locale yet (for fear of the English characters displaying as boxes, or having trouble changing it back), so I was wondering if anyone knew of any steam startup settings to run in a specific program in a Japanese locale, or any terminal commands that would function with proton. Since Proton is an offshoot of Wine I believe that commands that adjust wine should also adjust Proton, but I'm not sure of that so I didn't want to mess around too much and cause problems.

This isn't specifically about running in a Japanese locale though, so if anyone has any alternative solutions to display the characters that may be easier, I'm quite open to them.

Comment: To display Japanese characters properly, you need a font for the purpose. Can't help wondering which Ubuntu version and flavor you are using, since the `fonts-noto-cjk` package (including Japanese) is there by default AFAIK.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, adding to Gunnar, System Settings > Language, then select and install Japanese to use full service.